# Как использовать enum в QML

Tags: qt5, qml

Пытаюсь использовать enum в QML. Но код не срабатывает, окно пустое.

### Application Output:

13:07:20: Starting X:\QtPrograms\build-EnumTest-Desktop-Debug\debug\EnumTest...
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
qrc:/main.qml:20: ReferenceError: main is not defined
qrc:/main.qml:18: ReferenceError: main is not defined

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Text {
        id: name

        enum TextType {
                Normal,
                Heading
            }

                property int textType: main.TextType.Normal

                text: textType === main.TextType.Normal ? "Normal" : "Heading"
    }
}
```

Comment: Что такое `main`? Он нигде не определен и qt вам закономерно на это ругается. Попробуйте для начала приравнять тип нулю и проверить, сработает ли

Comment: @BeardedBeaver main это имя main.qml

Comment: Пытаюсь сделать как в примере http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#enumeration-attributes

Comment: Это всего лишь описание использования enum в qml, чтобы запустить его вам нужно создать QtQuick приложение

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Я так и сделал. Это QtQuick Application Просто выложил фрагмент.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Необходимо было добавить в ресурсы ещё один qml файл и использовать его в main.qml. Окончательный код выглядит так:

main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyText {

    }
}
```

MyText.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.10

Text {
    id: name

    enum TextType {
        Normal,
        Heading
    }

    property int textType: MyText.TextType.Heading
    text: textType ===  MyText.TextType.Normal ? "Normal" : "Heading"
}
```